# Is there any way to obtain security panel data

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, actionscript-3

I will show `Security.showSettings(SecurityPanel.LOCAL_STORAGE)` to show the local storage panel , I need to listen to any even to get what the user might have chosen when the security panel is closed

is there any possible way to get it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

First, SecurityPanel is not a stage accessible element.  The window is running above the VM layer of Flash, which limits you to the API [methods & properties listed by the framework](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Security.html).  This also means, you cannot attach event listeners to actions performed in the panel.

Secondly, were you to do some [reflection on the class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#describeType()), you'd find that you're still limited by what's outlined in the API reference, with nothing magical standing out.  Here's a screenshot of what you'll find.

[image: A snapshot of the Security class]

Sorry.  :/